# Error while doing Sign in with Facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, ipad

I made iPhone app, in which i have integrated **Sign in with Facebook**

When user clicks on **Sign in with Facebook** button in Developer device it works properly.

But after making app live on the store when user clicks on **Sign in with Facebook** button in non Developer device it doesn't works(it still works on Developer device)

In non developer device It asks for information that app would like to access your `basic info` user allows it, but after that it doesn't sign in, my activity indicator keeps animating.

**Code:**

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)
                            ok :(id<FBGraphUser>)_user {

    @try {

        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

        NSError* error;

       // fetching user info from Fb and storing it…


        [_ActInd stopAnimating];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
        @catch(NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception thrown =%@ ",exception);
    }

}
```

**Here is my screenshot of my developer.facebook.com account page:**

[image]:
I am not getting any exception, method is getting called, i mentioned above it work well in developer device (It doesn't work in non developer device)

***Please help am i doing mistake somewhere ?* OR do i need to change any thing after making app live ?**

Comment: Could you share your app id, please?

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/couponraja/id809755889?mt=8 available only for India.

Comment: Thanks, but I ment your Facebook App ID. Can you share that?

Comment: Facebook App ID = 385729024890577

Comment: @Krunal have you set the live app URL(iTunes URL) to FaceBook Dashboard?

Comment: Where to give Live iTunes Url ?

Comment: is there in to you code `loginViewFetchedUserInfo` fire or not.? if not then which type of error message you got please add in to you question.

Answer (score 3):

Please check your project build settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist file.
Did your project direct to the same info.plist? If not please check

- If FacebookAppID and FacebookDisplayName are the same as debug one.
- If bundle identifier in your info-plist is correct.

Comment: In `info.plist` file i have added 3 things **FacebookAppID** ,**URL Schemes** and **FacebookDisplayName** and in `dev.facebook.com` i have added new iOS platform there already added **Bundle identifier**, **iPhone store id**, **Single sign is on** and **deep linking is off** Do i need to add any thing more ?

Comment: I think you are doing fine as long as the FacebookAppID & Bundle in your dev.facebook.com are the same as your info.plist project setting.

Comment: In my project I have multi-info.plist for different release to customize different App name and version control. Just double check if this is the reason for the different behavior between debug & release.

Comment: I have 2 .plist file in my app, my app name and version control is also same as dev.facebook.com and in .plist file

Answer (score 3):

If you set your Facebook App for all user with green symbol. Just need to check that Setting **Bundle ID** in to facebook App page is same that you are using in to you Xcode project Bundle Identifier.

Here Bellow i just example login Method with FBLoginView controller. I dont think you need to submit app for review.

**in .h file** create One Button with `IBOutlet` and connect this button in to xib as we did normally

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>


@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController<FBLoginViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *FB_login; // just connect IBoutlate no need to give IBAction
    FBLoginView *loginview;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<FBGraphUser> loggedInUser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *profilePic; //this is for show profile pic or logged in user
```

**in .m File**

```
@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize profilePic = _profilePic;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    loginview =
    [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"email",nil] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends];

    loginview.frame =FB_login.frame;//CGRectMake(90,149, 280, 55);
    for (id obj in loginview.subviews)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton * loginButton =  obj;

            UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_fb_login.png"];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [loginButton sizeToFit];
        }
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel * loginLabel =  obj;
            loginLabel.text =@""; //@"Log in to facebook";
            loginLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            loginLabel.frame =CGRectMake(123,149, 280, 55);// CGRectMake(0, 0, 271, 37);
        }
    }

    loginview.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:loginview];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)LogOut:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    [self loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:loginview];
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *each in cookieStorage.cookies) {
        // put a check here to clear cookie url which starts with twitter and then delete it
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
    }
}

#pragma  mark------ FaceBook Sign In method------------

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {

    NSLog(@"Logged In");


}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    NSLog(@"%@",user);
    self.profilePic.profileID = user.id;





}
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    // Called after logout
    NSLog(@"Logged out");

    self.profilePic.profileID = nil;
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];


}
- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {
    // see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/ for general guidance on error handling for Facebook API
    // our policy here is to let the login view handle errors, but to log the results
    NSLog(@"FBLoginView encountered an error=%@", error);
}
```

**NOTE:-**
If you are trying to set Image of logged in user using `FBProfilePictureView` do not forget add `[FBProfilePictureView class];` in to app Delegate like Bellow

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [FBProfilePictureView class];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

**Here it is a sample code for you** [Sample code Facebook log-in with Image](http://ge.tt/9E2GFd41/v/0)

Comment: If i write this code, then i need to submit my app again for review ?

Comment: Nope i dont think that any need of submit app for facebook review

Comment: When i write your code it shows two buttons, `Sign in with Facebook` button i have added and `Login with facebook` i dont know from where it is coming. http://i.imgur.com/QwvZHAe.png

Comment: Code i wrote in viewController.m  `loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"basic_info",@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_about_me",nil] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends];
    
    loginview.frame =CGRectMake(90,149, 280, 55);
    
    loginview.delegate = self;
    
   // [self.view addSubview:loginview];
    
    [self.LoginScrollVw addSubview:loginview];`

Comment: that you just need to give frame as same as you button that you are setting in to you view controller

Answer (score 1):

Check for its sandbox mode,if it does not showing green circle(Shown in image) then you have to turn it on. After turning it on your app is available publicly.
[image]

Also check for country restriction

[image]

Comment: check for country restriction too

Comment: Where should i check ?

Answer (score 1):

I might have the similar situation. For newer app, if you ask permissions more than public_profile, email and user_friends, you need to submit your app for review.

What it is said from Facebook side:

> Review
>
> If your app asks for more than than public_profile, email and
>   user_friends it will require review by Facebook before your app can be
>   used by people other than the app's developers.
>
> The time to review your app is usually about 7 business days. Some
>   extra-sensitive permissions, as noted below, can take up to 14
>   business days.
>
> Learn more about our review process in our documentation on reviews.

From here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

Comment: I am asking User Email address, Birth date, location and basic info from user for that i need to submit my app for review to Facebook ? but my app is already live on the store, still i can submit my app for reviewal to fb ?

Comment: the FB review process **does not kick in for a year** (in about 2015)

Comment: @Krunal Yes, according to Facebook review policy, you just need to submit a simulator build

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have a pending submission? Please check your "Status & Review" tab in the Developer Dashboard, and see if you have any submission pending. If you have, you can't request that permission for non-test/developer users until it's approved.

Comment: Checked, i don't have any pending submission.